# How to sum a column from a query created table

Tags: sql

I created a SELECT query, after I execute it, it shows me a new table as I wanted (you can see it in the screenshot).

The problem is that I'm trying to add a new line to the query which supposes to sum() the column "Price" in the table that I got from the query

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE) AS totalPay 
FROM Meals
```

[You can see the tables here, and also the queries that worked at that, didn't.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EkoP.png)

I want it to be like that:

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHtcH.png)

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Add all information directly to your question as editable text

Comment: Sorry guys I didn't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the SUM(price) as new field in your first SELECT.
SELECT SUM(Meals.Price) as 'TotalPay', tableN01.waiterID
FROM tableN01 INNER JOIN Meals etc.